# JS same object as function parameter

Tags: javascript, object

[jiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckpvC/) - I've got function that creates `x*y array` with some default `value`. I want this value to be some array 2-long. But it seems that by passing `new Array(2)` as `parameter` it always pass the same object, so later changing any of cell in array affects all of them. How to make this array to have every `default` value the same for each cell, but `independent` too.

On fidle I change value of some field and alert other fields that depends on first one as every cell has default value as the same object.

Comment: Make a (shallow) copy: `result[i][j] = value.slice();`

Comment: Will it work with every type of value parameter? String/ multi-d array etc?

Comment: For that you need to create a deep copy of the array

Comment: @OPOPO: No, but the thing to understand is that while JavaScript is a pass-by-value language, you never actually have hold of an Object value... just a reference. So primitive types will automatically copy, but objects will only copy the reference. As such, Arrays need the manual copy operation. Plain Objects are a little more verbose to copy.

Comment: are you using any other third party libraries like jQuery

Comment: Yes, I use jQuery. Ok, so is there any more 'nice' method to copy object for each cycle of loop inside same function?

Comment: @OPOPO: If `value` could be any type, then you'll need to test to see what it is, and use the appropriate technique for each case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript - what you thing about it?

Comment: @OPOPO: I thing that question does not talk about arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've got function that creates `x*y` array with some default value. I want this value to be some array 2-long

But then it's not a `x*y` 2-dimensional array any more, but a `x*y*2` 3-dimensional array! And for that, you need a different function.

> it seems that by passing `new Array(2)` as parameter it always pass the same object, so later changing any of cell in array affects all of them.

Yes. `new Array(2)` creates *one* object, and your code constructs a 2-dimensional array with every field pointing to it.

> How to make them independent?

You'll need to use a different function, like

```
function newB(x, y, z) {
    var result = new Array(x);
    for (var i=0; i<x; i++) {
        result[i] = new Array(y);
        for (var j=0; j<y; j++) {
            result[i][j] = new Array(z);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var fields = newA(5, 5, 2);
```

Or to make it more general, you can use some factory function as a parameter, which constructs the independent values:

```
function newB(x, y, valuemaker) {
    if (typeof valuemaker != "function") {
        var value = valuemaker || 0;
        valuemaker = function(){ return value; };
    }
    var result = new Array(x);
    for (var i=0; i<x; i++) {
        result[i] = new Array(y);
        for (var j=0; j<y; j++) {
            result[i][j] = valuemaker();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var fields = newA(5, 5, function() {
    return new Array(2);
});
```